# Interfacing with CAN bus

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus

I am looking to write an application in C# and use both ARM based computers and x86 based computers. My question here is when using a J1939 to DB9 cable, do I need a specialized interface for the CAN bus protocol or would a serial port connection suffice?

Comment: Lots of posts about CAN bus on here? have you looked at any? Seems so similar to an earlier question...

Comment: see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/17634/10976

Comment: @SolarMike does not answer my question in terms of actually interfacing with the CAN bus. Yeah there are a lot of posts mentioning CAN bus but do not answer my specific question.

Comment: I just wonder how many mechanics will also be C# programmers who have spent the time doing what you want to do... Many mechs will be using the readers etc to tune cars etc, but perhaps you are on the wrong stack... Perhaps you should think about other stacks involving programming or ARM processors etc...

Comment: Yeah, you're more likely to find help from the EE / programming geeks than the motorheads

Comment: @mike65535 But remember... Whenever a question seems to be slightly car related ("J1939" in this case), it will be pushed from EE here. Somedays ago, someone had a "identify component" question on EE, and it was pushed here since the component was on the PCB of a dashboard. So what?

Comment: @sweber sorry, don't agree, not all car related questions get moved from EE, some stay there happily and are answered very competently...  Just have a look...

Comment: @SolarMike: Mathematically, "not all" means "at least one not" ;-) For me, far to many electric questions are migrated here, though they would better fit there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard for SubD9 connectors being used for CAN by almost any CAN device outside the automotive world. The pinout is:

```
1: N/C
2: CAN Low
3: Ground
4: N/C
5: Shield
6: Ground (Optional)
7: CAN High
8: N/C
9: Optional voltage to supply small devices
```

As you see, this isn't RS232, and for sure, your cable is nothing more than an adaptor between both connector types.

You DO need a CAN interface. Most commonly are USB CAN interfaces, but there are also serial CAN interfaces, or even driver ICs, which might be suitable for ARM based systems.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you google MCP2515 CAN Module.

You will find an interface module which "translates" CAN bus signals to Serial.

And you will find programming examples. I founds several for Arduino.